# How to enable/disable forefox addon using javascript

Tags: macos, firefox-addon

I want to enable the addon which is disabled manually after firefox restart .I can listen the events for enable/disable firefox addon with the methods "onDisabling: function(addon, needsRestart)" .Can I enable the extension using javascript.any ideas would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Add-on Manager API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager) for this. Something along these lines:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
AddonManager.getAddonByID("someextension@example.com", function(addon)
{
  if (addon.userDisabled)
    addon.userDisabled = false;
});
```

Here `someextension@example.com` stands for the ID of the add-on you want to enable of course.